# Surface plot with stat_contour: missing aesthetic z

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a surface plot with `stat_contour`. I have lat ("x") and long ("z") information and one continuous variable like altitude. My final goal is a plot like [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_contour-28.png).

The data:

```
x <-c(-21.035424, -21.120149, -21.059586, -21.092388,
    -20.992769, -21.013030, -21.125002, -21.147202,
    -21.122302, -21.072782, -21.040317, -21.117670,
    -21.121831, -22.529201, -22.572593, -22.522127,
    -22.566072, -22.610095, -22.586590, -22.644440,
    -22.471389, -22.673909, -22.548114)
y <-c(-51.001460, -50.884732, -50.983601, -51.042580,
     -50.979595, -50.808481, -50.921407, -50.884710,
     -50.888586, -50.802156, -50.898742, -51.059770,
     -50.918690, -51.767669, -51.774862, -51.842172,
     -51.865384, -51.620441, -51.703657, -51.697475,
     -51.729553, -51.522697, -51.670556)
z <- c(71.42857,  57.14286, 14.28571,  28.57143,  71.42857,  57.14286,
   85.71429,  57.14286, 42.85714,  57.14286, 100.00000,  57.14286,
   85.71429,  71.42857, 57.14286,  57.14286,  28.57143,  28.57143,
   71.42857,  57.14286, 42.85714,  42.85714,  85.71429)

df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

I used the following code:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z))
g + geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) + stat_contour()
```

But it didn't work

```
Error: stat_contour requires the following missing aesthetics: z
```

Why "z" is missing if I actually added in geom_tile. In `stat_contour` documentation there isn't a "z" aes.

Comment: isn't there a bracket missing? g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z))

Comment: you are taking the wrong principle. You can see this doing `df <- data.frame(expand.grid(x=x, y=y))`; `with(df, plot(x,y))`

Comment: Thank you @PauloCardoso, but where will "z" be added after using `expand.grid`?

Comment: z may be mapped to ggplot(aes()) as you'd done. with geom_tile your x and y should result in a grid for tilling.

Comment: @ThiagoToyoyoSouza, if my suggestion provided below answered your question you should accept the answer to close off the question.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way of doing this is as follows:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z))
g + stat_contour(geom='tile', aes(fill=..level..), binwidth=10)
```

The 'z' stat_contour() is looking for is the bin level (e.g. the height) of the contour.

However, the data you provided looks like this when you plot it out:
[image]

If this is your real data, you won't be able to calculate contours as you don't have enough data relative the local variation in z.  The example you provide (from the ggplot2 documentation) looks great because it has many more data points.